# Both Standby and ambient are Same in Android

Tags: android-wear-2.0, ambient, android-doze-and-standby

In Android smart watch,If device is not interactive then watch will enter from Interactive Mode to Ambient Mode

In this Google link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rwshwq_vI1s,they have explained only App StandBy and Doze mode

My Query here is Android Wear App flow will be from Interactive -> Ambient -> StandBy

or

Both App Standby and Ambient is Same?

Answer (score 0):

[Ambient Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/always-on) and [App Standby](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#understand_app_standby) are not the same, ambient mode allows your app to keep running on the foreground while staying visible to the user, and if your app is running on the foreground it will not enter to the stand by mode, see next paragraph:

> App Standby allows the system to determine that an app is idle when the user is not actively using it. The system makes this determination when the user does not touch the app for a certain period of time and none of the following conditions applies:

- **The app has a process currently in the foreground** (either as an activity or foreground service, or in use by another activity or
  foreground service).

As you can see the ambient mode allows you to stay on the foreground thus not allowing to enter Stand By, it's worth noting that to be able to use the Ambient Mode the user has to enable the option **Always on screen** on the device.

Comment: Ambient mode call backs(onEntryAmbient,onUpdateAmbient,onExitAmbient) gets called in code only If i enable "Always-on-Screen" option in Settings Page. If I didn't enable that option,App will go from Interactive to Standby Mode directly right?

Comment: Yes if you didn't enable that option the methods wouldn't get called, therefore it should go to standby mode.